# Right click without Actions in Selenium 3.x in Firefox browser

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, right-click, selenium3

How to right click an element without using Actions object. I get exception while using Actions in Selenium3 in FireFox  with GeckoDriver.
I have used the following code to set the GeckoDriver property.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", new File("lib/geckodriver").getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Robot class to right click on WebElement:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

and to set the system properties for gecko driver you can use the below line :

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
                            **path of your geckodriver.exe**");

Comment: If you found this (or any) answer helpful, please upvote it. If this answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Post the exception and detail which versions you are using (driver and FF).

Meanwhile, take a look at [this post](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3732). At it, the problem was related with a driver problem.